# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Query argument creationDateTime not found in the list of parameters provided during query execution

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to cover the case where the :creationDateTime is Null  to get the same result as the following query "SELECT o FROM ExtraNetOrder o". I searched it on the internet and found the solution by adding `IS NULL`, but it
does not work in my case. Currently I am getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Query argument
> creationDateTime not found in the list of parameters provided during
> query execution.

If the paramter :creationDateTime does not exist, then the query should be executed without the where parameter clause. In my table, I don't have creationDateTime with the NULL value.

In the final query I have 3 paramter which I am passing to the query. for the simplicity I added just one paramter (creationDateTime).

I am using EclipseLink in the projekt.

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="order_by_filter_options", query="SELECT o FROM ExtraNetOrder o "
            + " WHERE :creationDateTime IS NULL OR :creationDateTime = '' OR o.creationDateTime >=:creationDateTime ")
})

-------------------
Query q = em.createNamedQuery("order_by_filter_options");
if (fromDate != null)
    q.setParameter("creationDateTime", fromDate);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<ExtraNetOrder> orders = q.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set :creationDateTime to null if the fromDate is null. Just remove the `if` and always call `q.setParameter("creationDateTime", fromDate);`

Comment: It works thanks! Currenty I am not getting the right result. The where clause with the date has no effect in the query. I am getting the same result as without the where clause. I tried to use `query.setParameter("fromDate", fromDate, TemporalType.DATE);`. In the entity class I have the following annotation  '@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 protected Date creationDateTime;` but with no seccuss.